# Git issue with commit a cherry pick to other branch

Tags: git, gerrit

I have some issues with commiting a cherry pick from master branch to another branch as if I would try to commit from another account than mine and I get the following issue:
How could I do an authentication or something ?

```
account.. is not registered in your account, and you lack 'forge committer' permission
```

Comment: What hosting service are you using, Gitlab or Gerrit? As I know, Gerrit has the permission `forge committer`. You could ask your admin for help.

Comment: I'm using Gerrit

Comment: Check if the new commit's committer name and email(by `git log -1 $commit --pretty="%cn %ce"`) are consistent with the gerrit account in the remote `origin`(by `git remote -v`).

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't a git issue. Git doesn't have "forge committer" permissions

Comment: I'm not allowed to push anyting to that branch but as far as I've seen (commit 240..: invalid committer) .. is not the commit-id from the commit I want to push.

Comment: Gerrit and/or your source host has some sort of "are you allowed to claim to be this other person" check, and you're failing it. You'll need to ask your admins why they don't believe you are who you claim to be.